# What does "2k site rep" on Area51 stats page mean?

Tags: support

I see this on the [Area51 stats page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538?page=1&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top)
[image: 2k site rep]

My reputation is nowhere close to 2000 (not yet anyway), so what does the "2k site rep" mean? Looking at the other users on the page, looks like the reputation gets rounded up for this "label". Is this intentional, and if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it is a practical thing, since it appears only 3 digits are represented there. So that is why it is not represented with the whole number, and not with 1.5k (since this one has 4 digits, including the 'k').

Comment: Yup, it's just rounding as far as I can tell. That's why Madara, Krazer, and SingerOfTheFall all have 3k. But it doesn't apply any sort of rounding for <1k rep.